# Defining structs within structs & when to use the union?

Tags: c, nested, structure

I am declaring structures that contain information regarding a person:

> name
>   date/time added to the list
>   bloodtype
>   organ type needed

The information will later be compared against some information read in from a file, but I have a more general question for now.

Considering this implementation:

```
typedef struct {
    short month;
    short day; 
} dateT;

typedef struct {
    short hour;
    short minute;
} timeT;

typedef struct {
    char name[SIZE];
    char organName[SIZE];
    char bloodType[BT_LEN]; 
    dateT dateAdded;
    timeT timeAdded;
} personT;
```

If placing all of this information inside a single structure (without sub-structs) was not an option, is it more efficient to place these three related structures within a union or nest `dateT` and `timeT` inside `personT`?

Comment: Things within a union occupy the same space in memory, and you can only be using one the things at a time. Probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

A `union` would be a good choice if you only wanted one of many possible variable types within the `union` definition.  For example, if you only wanted time *or* date, you could do something like this:

```
typedef struct 
{
    short month;
    short day; 
} dateT;

typedef struct 
{
    short hour;
    short minute;
} timeT;

typedef union 
{ 
    dateT dateAdded;
    timeT timeAdded;
} myUnion;

myUnion.timeAdded.hour = 5; // timeAdded "exists"; dateAdded does not "exist"
myUnion.dateAdded.day = 7;  // timeAdded doesn't "exist" anymore; dateAdded "exists" now
```

Regarding your question how it is best to define structures and sub-structures, the answer is really up to you.  You could define a `struct` that holds all the data that you can possibly need, but it may be long and hard to read.  You could separate logical variables together into another `struct` if it makes sense.

You could define `dateT` and `timeT` within `personT` but the only benefit of that would be to prevent others from declaring a `struct` of that type.  They'd need to declare a `struct` of the `personT` type in order to have those types as a sub-type.

Comment: What do you mean by `...if you only wanted one of many possible variable types within the union definition.`? Within the union definition in your code you have included both time and date. If you declare an instance of myUnion you will have effectively created both time and date, right?

Comment: No, `union`s don't work like that. In the example I've given, you could only have `dateAdded` **OR** `timeAdded`, not both.  If you need both, use a `struct`.

Comment: @sherrellbc I added more stuff to the `union` answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: I did more research regarding this and it appears that whatever is contained within a union exists at the same location in memory and the required memory space takes on larger of the two datas. What is actually present at that location is memory is whatever was more recently set. It was my impression prior to this question that a union was a type that created a union in the sense that it was a huge structure or something. I see the differences now, thank you.

Comment: @sherrellbc Bravo for researching it and not just taking my word for it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what would you want to use union here for as you need both time and date info.

In general, I would use standard type [time_t](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time_t/) to represent the point in time and would then convert it into human-parseable time units (struct tm) via standard library functions like [localtime()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/localtime/)/[gmtime()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/gmtime/). That would save you some headaches dealing with time zones, daylight saving time changes, etc.